# Use a variable in a class

Tags: sass

Is there a way to use a variable based on a parent class?

I wish to use this color variable:

```
$primaryColor: #a59062;
```

And I'm using it fine like this:

```
button
{
background: $primaryColor;
}
```

But how can I change the $primaryColor value if a parent class should be over it? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$primaryColor: #a59062;

.hospitalityMode {
  $primaryColor: #4892C8;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want button inside `.hospitalityMode` to be different.

```
button
{
  background: $primaryColor;

  .hospitalityMode & {
    background: #4892C8;
  }

}
```